# how to select unique elements from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I had a dictionary of lists and I need to select unique elements out of all lists by dropping elements in lists if it repeats for the 2nd,3rd and so on.. times and preserving only for the first time it comes.
my data:

```
dicti={'a':['video@vermont.org'.,'nr@context'],
'b':['vermont@vermont.org','nr@id'],
'c':['nr@context''vermont@vermont.org']}
```

my code which I tried

```
checker=list()
for key in emails:
    for emailid in emails[key]:
        if emailid in checker:
            del(emailid)
        else:
            checker.append(emailid)
```

Comment: And what does the data look like?

Comment: data is a dict of list of email addresses

Comment: If you make me invent your data, I am much less likely to work on your problem.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the spirit of the original code:

```
checker=set()
for key in emails:
    value = list()
    for emailid in emails[key]:
       if emailid not in checker:
           checker.add(emailid)
           value.append(emailid)
    emails[key] = value
```

Comment: but why  my code is not working!!. i am not getting desired result

Comment: @AdityaMatturi What do you mean by "not working"? The result is not what you expect or the script crashes?

Comment: you are deleting if it is in checker and if not, you are adding lt to list but it should give same result if I just delete the element if it is in checker without adding anything new

Comment: `del(emailid)` is not doing what you assume. It is deleting a local variable called `emailid`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting why don't you fetch what you need from data ?

```
dicti={'a':['video@vermont.org','nr@context'],
'b':['vermont@vermont.org','nr@id'],
'c':['nr@context','vermont@vermont.org']}

track=[]
for key,value in dicti.items():
    for item in value:
        if item not in track:
            track.append(item)
print(track)
```

output:

```
['vermont@vermont.org', 'nr@id', 'nr@context', 'video@vermont.org']
```